# What software do dentists, opticians and similar professionals use to keep track of their clients' visits information?

Tags: crm

I am interested to know if there is any web based software that can do this.

By "this", I mean software that can keep track of, say, a dentist's patient data from the day the patient first walked in, and all their subsequent visits to date with notes, observations, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could give [HighRise](http://highrisehq.com/index3?source=37signals%20home) from 37signals a try. Also look at the [list of opensource healthcare software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_healthcare_software) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dentrix (CRM software), along with Infusionsoft (marketing) and Dentma  (Bridge between the 2)  Hope it helps.